# `::=` and `|` in Documentation

Tags: python, django, bnf

There are `::=` everywhere in Python Documentation:

For instance:

```
atom      ::=  identifier | literal | enclosure
```

I searched and learned it's BNF syntax.

It's really not easy to get a brief idea from dozens of files.

In python `:` can be considered as a variant of 'assignment' symbol `=`,

In Django's template syntax ,`|` is function symbol.

What are `::=`and `|` in BFN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Backus-Naur Form, which applies to many language grammars, `::=` means a definition of a certain element of syntax, almost like a macro. Per [the Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form):

> The "::=" means that the symbol on the left must be replaced with the expression on the right.

So, assuming a definition of the form:

```
symbol ::= expression
```

Means wherever `symbol` appears, replace with `expression`.

`|` means "or", as in `atom` is defined to either be an identifier, literal, or an enclosure. Again, from the Wikipedia page:

> more sequences are separated by the vertical bar "|", indicating a choice, the whole being a possible substitution for the symbol on the left.

Thus, the symbol on the left can be either of the many symbols in the left expression when separated by "|". In all, the documentation effectively says: "wherever there is an `atom`, it means that there could be a literal, identifier, or enclosure there".

Answer (score 0):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form):

> The "::=" means that the symbol on the left must be replaced with the expression on the right.

The `|` symbol stands for an exclusive `OR`.

So together that means that you have to replace the `atom` with either an `identifier`, a `literal` or an `enclosure`.